# Ubuntu 20.04: Fresh installation crashes before any prompt screen

Tags: 20.04, crash, usb-installation

I have made several attempts of performing a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04, but somehow, I am unable to. The installation abruptly crashes before any prompt/user-input screen could appear. Irrespective of whether I let the installer perform the disk scan or I simply skip it, the installer abruptly terminates within 15 seconds.

That is, when I create a bootable USB through Rufus. When I try to make a bootable USB through Unetbootin, it does not boot at all.

It would be really appreciable if anyone could help me getting my Ubuntu installed.

Comment: I would assume you have faulty install media.  If the validation of your installation media fails or doesn't complete - treat it as a failure & re-write your media (after validating your ISO).  The validation is of your installation media (not the disk itself, it's of ISO, thumb-drive, CD, DVD, or whatever installation media the ISO was written to). https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: If you can't complete the media-scan on the box you want to install to, I'd try and have it complete on another box; if it fails on hat box too - I'd take that as confirmation media write failed (ie. bad ISO or bad write to whatever media you wrote ISO to)

Answer (score 0):

The installation media as well as the iso, both were just fine. It seems the issue was with the default graphics driver that comes with the desktop iso. I booted through the **safe graphics** mode, and it worked decently.